# featureactivated is not firing

Tags: feature, site-template

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is feature activation code allowed in Web Template Project?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/is-feature-activation-code-allowed-in-web-template-project)

I am working on web template (aka site template). It a farm level solution so vs 2010 automatically added a feature scoped to farm. I added a 2nd feature scoped to web. because I want to do bunch of thing using object model when a web (sub site) is provisioned. It runs good, i can click on new site> select my custom template > create a site > it creates the site. I am just adding a dummy list to proof my concept that event receiver will work. I even put a breakpoint in the code and it simply doesnt get fire. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Is your web scope feature added to the WebFeatures element in the onet.xml?

Comment: Why are you opening up a new question on this? You already asked and got help regarding this in this recent Q: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/is-feature-activation-code-allowed-in-site-template-project If you feel that you need better response, you should add more info to existing Q instead of abandoning older one